# In windows 8, how do you create a shortcut to kill a specific program?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using a modded version of Skyrim which semi-regularly freezes and the only way to close it that I've found is to sign out and in again. So I was wondering if it was possible to create a shortcut, which I can then assign a hotkey for, which will execute the command prompt for killing the current Skyrim running program?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new shortcut to say cmd.exe.
Then edit the shotcut and change the target to

> C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe /IM Notepad.exe

Instead of Notepad.exe, add the name of your application.
But I am not sure if this will kill SkyRim if it is elevated (Run as administrator).

Comment: taskkill is the way to go but why does he need to create a shortcut to cmd.exe first? Can't he just directly create a shortcut to taskkill.exe instead?

Comment: @Karan I wanted to say make shortcut to anything e.g. cmd